# com.algorithmia.APIException: 308 unexpected API response

Tags: java, http, httpclient, http-status-code-308, algorithmia

I'm using algorithmia, a repository of trained ML functions on the Internet. Few weeks ago, an issue showed up, and since then, haven't been able to figure out what's going on. I'm executing this code, which can be found on their official site.

```java
import com.algorithmia.Algorithmia;
import com.algorithmia.AlgorithmiaClient;
import com.algorithmia.algo.AlgoResponse;
import com.algorithmia.algo.Algorithm;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String input = "A purely peer-to-peer...";
        AlgorithmiaClient client = Algorithmia.client("api_key");
        Algorithm algo = client.algo("nlp/Summarizer/0.1.8");
        algo.setTimeout(300L, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS); //optional
        AlgoResponse result = algo.pipe(input);
        System.out.println(result.asJsonString());
    }

}
```

But this code raises the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.algorithmia.APIException: 308 unexpected API response: 
    at com.algorithmia.algo.Algorithm.pipeRequest(Algorithm.java:145)
    at com.algorithmia.algo.Algorithm.pipe(Algorithm.java:96)
    at Main.main(Main.java:13)
```

**I want to help out**

1. Create a maven project
2. Add this maven dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.algorithmia</groupId>
  <artifactId>algorithmia-client</artifactId>
  <version>[,1.1.0)</version>
</dependency>
```

3. Paste the code showed above

**Further observations and guessings**

- Issuing a cURL request everything works as expected
- Using Python works fine
- It may have something to do with `HttpClient`
- The Java code will work with a proxy like `Charles`
- Refer to the [opened issue](https://github.com/algorithmiaio/algorithmia-java/issues/17) on GitHub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the current date, 2nd July 2019, they published version `1.0.16` that fix such error.